# Guzzle6 and json

Tags: json, php7, guzzle

Доброго времени суток, появилась вот такая проблема:(
Я понятие не имею с чем это связанно .

Пример 1:

```
$array = json_decode($response1->getBody()->getContents(), true);
echo $response1->getBody()->getContents();//
var_dump($array); // NULL
echo json_last_error_msg();//Syntax error
```

---

Пример 2

```
$array = json_decode($response1->getBody(), true);
echo $response1->getBody();//{"status":"false","message":"Site not found"}
var_dump($array); // NULL
echo json_last_error_msg();//Syntax error
```

---

Как это решить? это универсальная проблема для всех сайтов. Обратился на github и выгнали сюда .
Сайт отвечает стандартным JSON а json_decode говорить synatx error

### Версия php 7.1

Стоит добавить что json_decode((string)$response1->getBody(), true); тоже не дает результатов.

Внутри $response1->getBody() находится такой JSON: {"status":"false","message":"Site not found"}
jsond_decode парсить его не хочет// Synatx Error
а если вручную сделать json_decode('{"status":"false","message":"Site not found"}') то все ок.

Comment: Decoding: {"status":false,"message":"timer"} - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка «syntax error, malformed JSON» на простом JSON-е](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720810/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-syntax-error-malformed-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-json-%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такие вот чудеса безопасности изобретают люди))) мистики не бывает, проблема была в скрытом символе .
[Помогли решить проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720810/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5)