# Ошибка «syntax error, malformed JSON» на простом JSON-е

Tags: php, json

Ошибка появляется  при попытке разбора данного простого JSON-а:

```
json_decode('{"status":false,"message":"Site not found"}');
```

Что тут не так? JSON является же корректным.

***P. S.:*** Данная строка была скопирована из [одной документации](https://ru.functions-online.com/json_decode.html?command=%7B%22json%22:%22%5Cufeff%7B%5C%22status%5C%22:false,%5C%22message%5C%22:%5C%22Site%20not%20found%5C%22%7D%22%7D).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Между одинарной кавычкой и `{` у вас в строке скрытый символ стоит.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74f4bcd2c80646c388bf84b1761b35969b9aba90

Если его удалите, то вместо `NULL` вернет:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["status"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["message"]=>
  string(14) "Site not found"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо ))))) блин сколько же я мучался, я уже заметил, я понял что мистики не бывает, определил кодировку и с помощью iconv сменил кодировку на UTF-8. Вот тогда он и показался)))) п»ї{"status":false,"message":"Site not found"}